# Serilog Destructure.ByTransforming<Interface>() not working

Tags: c#, serilog

I would like Serilog to destructure any class that implement an interface (so I don't have to manually include them all.) The following doesn't seem to work:

```
public interface ITest { }

public class Test : ITest { }

public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Destructure.ByTransforming<ITest>(i => new { str = "Blah" })
            .CreateLogger();

        Log.Logger.Debug("We have issues with {@test}", new Test());
    }
}
```

Instead of getting `{str="Blah"}` as I do with a class destructure, I get `{}`
Is there a trick to getting the destructuring to trigger for all that implement the interface?

Comment: `.Destructure.ByTransformingWhere<dynamic>(type=>type.GetInterface(nameof(ITest)) is { } , _ => new { str = "Blah" })`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found one way to do it. I couldn't find any documentation or examples online, but I flailed and figured out how to use a Destructuring Policy. Simply create a class that inherits from `IDestructuringPolicy` and implement the `TryDestructure` method. As parameters of `TryDestructure`, you will get the value to be destructured, a factory object that you can use to construct the result, and the last param is an out param of the result. The function should return `true` if the destructuring was a success and `false` otherwise.

I created a destructuring policy that checks the type of the incoming object. If it matches the interface type that I want, I destructure it like normal and return true.

Here is an example of one I created:

```
 public class ResponseDestructuringPolicy : IDestructuringPolicy
 {
   public bool TryDestructure(object value, ILogEventPropertyValueFactory propertyValueFactory, out LogEventPropertyValue result)
   {
     if (value is IResponse response)
     {
       result = propertyValueFactory.CreatePropertyValue( new {response.Message} );
       return true;
     }

     result = null;
     return false;
   }
}
```

You then hook it to the logger when creating it like so:

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
     .Destructure.With(new ResponseDestructuringPolicy())
     .CreateLogger();
```

The `Destructure.With()` function can take as many polices as you want. It looks like Serilog checks for registered type destructures then it will run through each policy and run the `TryDestructure` functions on each until it gets `true`. If no `true` is received, it will go on to destructure the default way.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @guido's comment to the OP's question, add this extension method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Extensions for Serilog's LoggerDestructuringConfiguration
/// </summary>
public static class LoggerDestructuringConfigurationEx
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The built in ByTransforming matches an exact type. Use ByTransformingFromBase to specify a base class or interface 
    /// </summary>
    public static LoggerConfiguration ByTransformingFromBase<TBase>(this LoggerDestructuringConfiguration loggerDestructuringConfiguration, Func<TBase, object> transformation) 
        => loggerDestructuringConfiguration.ByTransformingWhere<dynamic>(type => type.IsAssignableTo(typeof(TBase)), obj => transformation(obj));
}
```

Then use ByTransformingFromBase instead of ByTransforming.

```
    var logger = new Serilog.LoggerConfiguration()
        .Destructure.ByTransformingFromBase<IFoo>(foo => ...)
        .CreateLogger();
```